# query to overwrite the record in duplicate instances

Tags: mysql

```
|student_id |subject    |marks|
|
|1001       english     75|
|1001       maths       80|
|1001       science     70|
|1001       english     90|
|1001       maths       95|
|1001       science     85|
```

required output:

```
student_id  English Maths Science
1001        75        80        70
1002        90        95        85
```

so how to get the result as expected am new to sql. Thanks in advance and note that the records are having 1001 as ids intentionally

Comment: what had you tried?

Comment: I tried grouping it by student id and subject but didn't know how to update the value at runtime, and also i was able to achieve the pivoting with the help of case statement

Comment: If you want to generate new group labels that's fine, but your starting data will need one or more columns which would allow us to do this.  Right now, your data doesn't have enough information.

Comment: Are you sure your student ids in table 1 are correct? There is no student with id 1002 there, so how would you know which records to assign to that id in the second table?

Comment: @buddemat yes the data is correct. thats where I'm feeling tricky. while retrieving we should be incrementing by 1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i didn't get you. from student table i need to retrieve the expected output where for the repetitive entry of subjects i should be incrementing the student id while displaying

Comment: SQL has no concept of order unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause. Depending on the implementation the records will be returned however it wants without any guarantee of consistency. If you intend to rely on the order for anything, you must specify your desired order using `ORDER BY`. This is not possible in your data.